.NET 8 on Windows Server 2022 throwing Server Error 500
I have just installed a fresh new Windows Server 2022 and installed .NET 8 hosting package etc.
When I add my very simple sample app and trying to reach, it throws me SERVER ERROR 500 (no details given)
My web.config file look like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
        <handlers>
            <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\test.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
        </system.webServer>
      </location>
</configuration>

What am I doing wrong here?
My app-pool settings look like these:



These two lines, which are throwing the error and it doesn't show the detailed error even when I have errormMode to Detailed.
<add name="aspNetCore"
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet"


Does this answer your question? Deploying website: 500 - Internal server error

@HansPassant it didnt help!

Sure it does, helps you write a much better question.
